# Customize hoverinfo of ggplotly() in a bupaR:: activity frequency plot

Tags: r, ggplotly, bupar

How can you set the hoverinfo of `ggplotly(`) in a activity frequency plot of `bupaR` to `Activity:` and `Absolute Activity Frequency:` ?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(processmapR)
library(eventdataR)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "decio"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    plotlyOutput("activity_frequency"),

    )
    
)
  


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  sip<-bupaR::simple_eventlog(eventlog = eventdataR::sepsis,
                              case_id = "case_id",
                              activity_id = "activity",
                              #activity_instance_id = "activity_instance_id",
                              timestamp = "timestamp",
                              #lifecycle_id = "lifecycle",
                              resource_id = "resource"
  )
  output$activity_frequency <- renderPlotly({
    
    ggplotly(sip %>% activity_frequency("activity") %>% plot())
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Give all the data necessary to run the app please

Comment: sepsis is coming from the eventDataR package

Comment: did you see data sepsis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want in your tooltips, so I'm just going to show you a way you could change them.

When I realized you were using a function called `activity_frequency` and you named the Plotly output the same thing, I made a change. I changed the call in `ui` and `server` from `activity_frequency` to `act_freq`.

I created a function that modifies the tooltips. Inside `server`, after calling `ggplotly`, you'll run the plot through that function.

This function will make your tooltips look like this.

[image]

It's not particularly informative (since that information is already there). However, it's still a big change from the default, which looks like this.

[image]

I put this function before the call to create `ui`.

```
hoverFix <- function(plt) {
  dat <- invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(i) {
      txt <- plt$x$data[[i]]$text
      # original pattern: "reorder(activity, absolute): Release E<br />
      #                    absolute:    6<br />
      #                    absolute:    6"
      plt$x$data[[i]]$text <- gsub(pattern = "^.*(\\:.*)<.*(\\:.*)<.*",
                                    "Activity\\1 <br />Frequency\\2",
                                    txt)
      plt$x$data[[i]]
    } # end inner function
  ) # end lapply
  ) # end invisible
  plt$x$data <- dat
  plt # return entire plot
} # end outer function
```

Then I modified the call to create `output$act_freq <- renderPlotly({` so that the function was called. You've already used the `({` instead of `(`, so you can list multiple steps in the call.

Here is the entire `server`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  sip <- simple_eventlog(eventlog = sepsis,
                         case_id = "case_id",
                         activity_id = "activity",
                         timestamp = "timestamp",
                         resource_id = "resource")
  output$act_freq <- renderPlotly({
    plt <- ggplotly(sip %>% activity_frequency('activity') %>% plot())
    plt <- hoverFix(plt)
    plt
  })
}
```

[image]

Just so we're totally clear, here is all the code together.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(processmapR)
library(eventdataR)
library(plotly)
library(edeaR)

hoverFix <- function(plt) {
  dat <- invisible(lapply(
    1:length(plt$x$data),
    function(i) {
      txt <- plt$x$data[[i]]$text
      # original pattern: "reorder(activity, absolute): Release E<br />
      #                    absolute:    6<br />
      #                    absolute:    6"
      plt$x$data[[i]]$text <- gsub(pattern = "^.*(\\:.*)<.*(\\:.*)<.*",
                                    "Activity\\1 <br />Frequency\\2",
                                    txt)
      plt$x$data[[i]]
    } # end inner function
  ) # end lapply
  ) # end invisible
  plt$x$data <- dat
  plt # return entire plot
} # end outer function

data(sepsis, package = "eventdataR")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "decio"),
  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(plotlyOutput("act_freq"))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  sip <- simple_eventlog(eventlog = sepsis,
                         case_id = "case_id",
                         activity_id = "activity",
                         timestamp = "timestamp",
                         resource_id = "resource")
  output$act_freq <- renderPlotly({
    plt <- ggplotly(sip %>% activity_frequency('activity') %>% plot())
    plt <- hoverFix(plt)
    plt
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```